# Using PHP requires not finding class constructor

Tags: php

I don't know why I am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'ctwitter_stream' not found in C:\wamp\www\twitter.tld\index.php on line 11
```

This is my code

```
<?php
    require 'ctwitter_stream.php';
    $t = new ctwitter_stream();
    $t->login("x", "y", "z", "z");
    $t->start(array('facebook', 'fbook', 'fb'));
?>
```

But In the same directory I've got the file `ctwitter_stream.php`.

```
class ctwitter_stream
{
    private $m_oauth_consumer_key;
    private $m_oauth_consumer_secret;
    private $m_oauth_token;
    private $m_oauth_token_secret;

    private $m_oauth_nonce;
    private $m_oauth_signature;
    private $m_oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    private $m_oauth_timestamp;
    private $m_oauth_version = '1.0';

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
        // set a time limit to unlimited
        //
        set_time_limit(0);
    }
```

Comment: your ctwitter_stream.php, you have started this file with `<?php` right?

Comment: Try `require __DIR__.'/ctwitter_stream.php';`. If you are still getting an error then the file is either not in the same directory or unreadable.

Answer (score -1):

> Verify the file{ctwitter_stream.php} path and permission. It should
>   work

.

Comment: This is hardly a constructive answer. If paths or permissions would be wrong, the error would be different. At best you should post this as a comment (for which you do not yet have enough reputation, and you're not helping yourself getting there by posting such answers).